# In Javascript, why is there no "prototype" property for an instance or object literal?

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming, prototype, prototype-programming

In Javascript, any "function object" has a prototype

```
> F = function() {}
F()
> F.prototype
F {}
```

But "object" or "instance" doesn't have a prototype

```
> o = {}
Object {}
> o.prototype
undefined
> f = new F()
F {}
> f.prototype
undefined
```

However, the built-in object "Function" and "Object" have a prototype:

```
> Function.prototype
Empty()
> Object.prototype
Object {}
```

This looks quite confusing for me.

1. `Function` and "function object" have a prototype property
2. `Object` has a prototype property, but "object literal" and "instance object" doesn't have a prototype property

What does the `prototype` property actually mean? In the example above, shouldn't the `prototype` property of `f` be `F`?

Does anyone have ideas about how to explain this? Thanks!

Comment: An instance is an object, and objects are not functions. `Object` and `Function` are functions (constructors). Note "object" (as in `{}`) vs "Object" as in anything that is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't confuse the prototype attribute of a function with the internal prototype of an object (which places the object in the prototype chain).

`Function` and `Object` are constructor functions, as such, they have a prototype attribute, which will be assigned as the internal prototype of objects created with these constructor functions.

I recommend **Eloquent Javascript**'s chapter ["The secret life of objects"](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html), particularly for this quote:

> It is important to note the distinction between the way a prototype is associated with a constructor (through its `prototype` property) and the way objects *have* a prototype (which can be retrieved with `Object.getPrototypeOf`). The actual prototype of a constructor is Function.prototype since constructors are functions. Its `prototype` *property* will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its *own* prototype.